# To change URL to user friendly URL

Tags: seo, url, asp.net

I'm refactoring my ASP.net application from ASP.net 3.5 to 4.0. Also I'm changing the URLs to user friendly URLs `/product.aspx?id=100` to `/product-name/100`.

All my pages are indexed by search engines and the site has already been online for 6 years. I'm planning to do 301 redirect from the old pages to the new one.

I want to make sure I won't lose the rankings and traffic.

Any suggestion how to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [301 redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php). This will tell the search engines, and your users, where to find those pages under their new URL. This will preserve the rankings of any pages this is done for.

Comment: How about canonical?

Comment: @SimonWalker Although you could technically do this, 301's are a much better practice, especially if the prior page ceases to exist. You need a way to pass old backlinks to the proper page and a canonical, while it will pass authority, won't redirect the user from an old link.